# How to rename the x-labels in a violinplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels, violin-plot

I have made a ***violinplot*** and want to rename the x-labels .

```
  ax = sns.violinplot(x="Week_Number", y="Ammonia", data=Res)
```

this is the output:

[image]

And What I want to Have is , rather than 1 I want ***Week 1*** , than for 44 i Want ***Week 2*** until ***Week 10*** for 52.

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to `set_xticklabels` property ([doc](https://doc.ebichu.cc/matplotlib/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html)). To apply this function, you need to have the axis. There is the same for y labels with `set_yticklabels`.

Here the code is adapted from [Seaborn examples](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/simple_violinplots.html):

```
# Import modules
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create your list of labels
week_list = ["Week_" + str(i) for i in range(1, 10)]
# ['Week_1', 'Week_2', 'Week_3', 'Week_4', 'Week_5', 'Week_6', 'Week_7', 'Week_8', 'Week_9']

fig = plt.figure()                  # Create a new figure for getting axis
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)           # Get the axis

# Create a random dataset across several variables
rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
n, p = 40, 8
d = rs.normal(0, 2, (n, p))
d += np.log(np.arange(1, p + 1)) * -5 + 10

# Use cubehelix to get a custom sequential palette
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(p, rot=-.5, dark=.3)

# Show each distribution with both violins and points
sns.violinplot(data=d, palette=pal, inner="points")

week_list = ["Week_" + str(i) for i in range(1,10)]

# Set the x labels
ax.set_xticklabels(week_list)

# Show figure
plt.show()
```

[image]